# Algorithm to Compress Consecutive Repeats of Data

Tags: compression, string-matching

I'm looking for an algorithm that is able to identify and compress consecutive repeats of data, rather than repeats of earlier data; think like LZ but instead of using length/offset pairs using length/count pairs where the source is always immediately preceding the copies, allowing decompression at consumption with a simple loop counter. This is a common mechanism in retro music engines, but was typically done by hand in the day. Ideally it would generate the smallest possible compression where multiple different compressions might be possible for a source data.

Some musing from 2 days later:
LZ is close to useful for this purpose but not quite. I think 3 modifications to it would make it work.

1. A prefix only matches in the sliding window if the end of the match would be the end of the sliding window. This ensures that it's creating loops rather than references to arbitrary locations in the sliding window.
2. When a match is found, it reads ahead in the input to determine how many times the match repeats (LZ's RLE mechanic but quantized to full loops).
3. A decision tree is created. Each time a loop is found, branches for loop and no loop are created, and processing continues down both paths until all are completed at which point the shortest total branch is used as the encoding. This makes it non-greedy and prevents it always taking the first loop that might be smaller than a later loop since unlike LZ it is unable to handle matches contained in matches.

So for the alphanumeric tokens 0001 2223 2223 2223 2223 24 5656 5678 9999 222A, the first candidate would be 3x0, which ought to be looped. But 3x0 1 3x2 3 would be a greedy mistake; it needs to wait for 3x0 1 4x2223, which is made possible by the decision tree (in contrast declining the 3x0 loop would create a useless branch).

I'll see about trying to implement it. Any comments?